# Bad query syntax when querying couchdb lucene from php (with curl) with non latin characters

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, lucene, couchdb

i 've created a generic search form with php to query couchdb-lucene full text.
sample code:

```css
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
  
$varKeyword = $_POST['formKeyword'];
 
  
$ch = curl_init();
   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://00.000.00.158:5984/_fti/local/elod_empty/_design/sellerAll/In_All_Json?q=".$varKeyword);
echo($varKeyword);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Accept: */*'
            ));
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo($response);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
 <title>search Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search2.php" method="post">
  <p>
   enter search keyword<br>
   <input type="text" name="formKeyword" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varKeyword;?>" />
   <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
   <input type="submit" name="formClear" value="clear">
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

problem is i cannot search non latin characters (greek) > Result is:

```
{"reason":"Bad query syntax: Cannot parse '': Encountered \"\" at line 1, column 0.\nWas expecting one of:\n ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n ...\n ...\n ...\n ...\n ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n ...\n ...\n \"*\" ...\n ","code":400}
```

while:
1) i am getting latin results if my keyword is latin
2) i get non latin results if i query couchdb from command prompt (ubuntu 14.04) or any browser with non latin
e.g.

```
http://00.000.00.158:5984/_fti/local/elod_sellers/_design/sellerAll/In_All_Json?q='non latin'
```

or

```
curl http://00.00.00.158:5984/_fti/local/elod_sellers/_design/sellerAll/In_All_Json?q='non latin'
```

couchdb version is 1.5.0. and lucene 1.0.2
couchdb lucene log says: "org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8"

Any suggestion would be really helpful!

Comment: You may have done your curl request/response with utf-8, but you also have to issue a utf-8 charset header for your php->client response. since you haven't, the browser's free to use any charset it wants and will just pick its default.

Comment: thank u Marc, i 'll certainly give that a try!

Comment: you can set the accept-charset in the form. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902062/php-form-submit-utf8

Comment: Thank u both, beginner 's mistakes!

Comment: You can both post them as answers so i can close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="search2.php" method="post">
```

is replaced by:

```
<form action="search2.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: to flaggers: this is what solved op's problem to his own problem. For answering this question's sake, please stop flagging it as low quality

Comment: Thank u felix, was just trying to close an old issue.