# How PHP knows encoding of textual data when parsing POST 'multipart/form-data' input?

Tags: php, input, encoding, multipartform-data

I wonder how exactly PHP detects encoding of input data which came from HTTP request.

Imagine API which accepts requests from various clients (mobile apps maybe, not from browsers). The incoming request has header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and by this, no additional encoding information was given.

Let's say that there was a text field within the POST body and I want to apply validation on it. **How do I know the encoding I should use?**

I found no clear answer in the documentation so please help. I guess, I may look at Mbstring extension which has `mb_check_encoding()` and it could be used for this purpose. Is it a reliable way?

**How client can say which encoding they used when sending `multipart/form-data` POST request:**
As RFC-7578 says (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.4) each part of `multipart/form-data` payload can have its own `Content-Type` information. Which solves a problem of communicating encoding information.

Comment: You 'expect' the encoding based on how you defined it in the html header. Then you also set your php encoding to match (dont mix encodings). If someone is submitting a form with an altered encoding, then the data will be garbage either way.

Comment: This is probably the best answer I've seen after a quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572638/2960971

Comment: I imagine that this is API which accepts POST requests with multibyte/form-data encoding. There is no HTML form just some "client" (maybe a mobile app or anything else) which sends a request. How is backend to behave in that case?

Comment: If its an API, then there should be a spec that clients are following to ensure proper connectivity in request and response. If the client is unable to properly send data, then they really shouldn't be given access to the API.

Comment: I understand that string has no encoding information attached in this case. 
I understand that clients can use any encoding they want(support) to make a textual string (since multibyte/form-data just transfers any bits client sent).

However, the backend cannot make safe validation until it knows the encoding. I think the question should be corrected to "What way I can detect an encoding of any string in PHP?".

Comment: @Randall, yes soft rules (documentation) is a way to know encoding. But backend can't generally trust clients.

Comment: Certainly is the question isn't it? If someone isn't following the spec to communicate with the API right, do you think they would follow another spec to send what they encoded it as? hehe! ... Bottom line though, its really hard to figure out what encoding something is in *after the fact*, when its not as expected (or conveys such). You can run through all the encoding methods trying to logically match what it could be, but in the end its not going to be 100% accurate. One of the things I despise about the whole clusterfudge that is charset encodings ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are actually two problems:

1. How to communicate encoding that was used for text creation (in case of transferring it with `multibyte/form-data` method);
2. How to detect what real encoding was used for text creation;

The first problem is a problem of communication and can be solved both by reading a documentation as well as providing an additional explicit header for text section within request payload. See [RFC-7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.4) for details.

The second problem has no proper solution. It is hard to detect the actual encoding that was used to assemble the text. Though, you can guess with functions like [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php).